# Error for dropdown list : OnSelectedIndexChange

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, dropdown

I'm trying to create two dropdown lists connected to each other from the database, which are department and doctor. First dropdown is department and the other is doctor. According to the department id doctor belongs to, the second dropdown list should return doctors. I'm almost sure my code is right, but I'm getting this strange error:

> CS1061: 'patient_newappointment_aspx' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Department_Changed' and no extension method 'Department_Changed'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'patient_newappointment_aspx' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**asp.x file**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Department</td>
                <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DDLDepartment" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Department_Changed"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Doctor:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLDoctor" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>

                        </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CareAndCureFull.Patient
{
    public partial class NewAppointment : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CareandCure"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack) {

                string query = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Department";
                BindDropDownList(DDLDepartment, query, "Name", "ID", "Select Department");
                DDLDoctor.Enabled = false;
                DDLDoctor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Doctor", "0"));

            }
        }

        protected void Department_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DDLDoctor.Enabled = false;
            DDLDoctor.Items.Clear();
            DDLDoctor.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Doctor", "0"));
            int DepartmentId = int.Parse(DDLDepartment.SelectedItem.Value);
            if (DepartmentId > 0)
            {
                string query = string.Format("SELECT ID, FirstName FROM Doctor WHERE DepartmentID = {0}", DepartmentId);
                BindDropDownList(DDLDoctor, query, "FirstName", "ID", "Select Doctor");
                DDLDoctor.Enabled = true;
            }

        }

        private void BindDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, string query, string text, string value, string defaultText)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            using (conn)
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    ddl.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ddl.DataTextField = text;
                    ddl.DataValueField = value;
                    ddl.DataBind();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(defaultText, "0"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLDoctor" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true">
```

Removing the AutoPostBack here solved the problem.